# How do you set DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME in styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-dialogfragment, android-styles

How do you set DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, which hides the frame, in your styles.xml file? Or does this have to be done outside of the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link.
[Put STYLE_NO_FRAME in styles.xml](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=PZj4AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=style_no_frame%20in%20styles&source=bl&ots=8SQt4nmwEr&sig=QrVEOgB6tYbwjg8XHAaehK6F0zs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCGoVChMI-Z6i1rPzxgIVYdymCh3g7g1-#v=onepage&q=style_no_frame%20in%20styles&f=false)

```
<style name="DialogWindowAnim">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_from_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down_to_bottom</item>
    </style>

<style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="DialogWindowAnim">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogWindowAnim</item>
</style>
```

This is how I did it.